# Sql query to calculate first occurrence of a sales order not fulfilled by stock

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

1. Sales Orders (SO ) with fields:Part, Due_Date, Qty
2. Part with fields Part and Stock.

I an trying to write a query that will produce the first occurrence ( by date - SO.Due_Date) that a sales order (SO.Qty) cannot be fulfilled by the stock.

This is easy if there is no stock i.e. Part.Stock=0 or if there is only one sales order for the part (SO.Qty > Part.Stock)

If there are multiple sales orders I only want the first one shown e.g.

```
Part.Part = Box , Part.Stock = 250
SO.Part | SO.Due_Date | SO.Qty
Box     | 26/10/2014  | 100
Box     | 27/10/2014  | 100
Box     | 28/10/2014  | 100  * Return this row
Box     | 29/10/2014  | 100
```

I think I need a sub query or need to use CTE but I can't work it out unless I use a loop. The tables have thousands of parts and sales orders and I am trying to run this query as quickly as possible.

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I don't get it. By what column(s) do you want to group, why is the `28/10/2014` row the desired row? It's not the first row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is a learning exercise, as no real business would work this way. 
Anyway, here is a query to do what you want:

```
select *
from sales_order as so1
where due_date = 
 (select min(due_date)
  from sales_order as so2
  inner join part as p on p.part = so2.part
  where so1.part = so2.part
  and stock < (
    select sum(quantity)
    from sales_order as so3
    where so3.due_date <= so2.due_date
    and so3.part = so2.part
    )
  )
```

Which I have put into a working fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd8ab5/1
There are some assumptions such as one order per date, but I believe it answers the question.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and for showing on SQL fiddle. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

A query that uses a self join to calculate the running quantity total for each row and selects the row with the smallest due date having a running total greater than p.stock

```
select so.part, so.due_date, so.quantity
from sales_order so
join part p on p.part = so.part
join sales_order so2 on so2.part = so.part 
  and so2.due_date <= so.due_date
where p.part = 'Box'
group by so.part, so.due_date, so.quantity
having sum(so2.quantity) > max(p.stock)
order by so.due_date limit 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. I will try your suggestion but may have to edit for many different parts not just 'Box'. I am unable to try it out on the development system (my laptop) as the boss has just taken it as his girlfriend threw his down the stairs over the weekend. I may get mine back tomorrow!